# Trading backoffice solution

Tags: java, jms, system, trading

Is there any open source solution for trading settlement, i.e. something similar to NYSE settlement system that handles the market transactions?

In other words, something similar to the software stacks that have to be implemented for a new stock exchange for example?

Lots of focus/questions have been about trading platform from end-user point of view, but not the backoffice solutions that handles gazillions transactions..

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% clear on what you are asking for.  I'm going to assume you are looking for some kind of market simulator for back testing an automated trading strategy, and not the actual software that the market makers (ie NYSE) use to fulfill orders from clients.

This is a huge topic, and the answer really depends on the type trading you want to do.  Are you trading commodities, stocks, futures, forex?  Any market simulator that will let you simulate trades will need to model all of the specific rules for that market.  One of the hardest problems associated with this is getting clean reliable data to feed into your market simulator.  Garbage in, garbage out and all that applies here.

Once you have chosen your market, then you need to focus you research there.  Each market has its own tools and platforms.  Two good resources for traders are www.elitetrader.com and www.wilmott.com.  Both sites are full of knowledgeable people who can help you choose your tools and develop a trading strategy.

Good luck.

Comment: I AM looking for the actual software that the market makers (i.e. NYSE) use to fulfill orders. Any idea?

Comment: @portoalet  Sorry I can't answer your question.  The guys over at willmott or elitetrader will probably know.  I'm almost certain its a homegrown solution and not a vendor app.  Closely guarded trade secrets and all that.

Answer (score 0):

[QuickFIX/J](http://www.quickfixj.org/) is a Java version of the QuickFIX opensource FIX engine. 
It is optimized as a FIX messaging app, not as a matching engine. But it can generate all of the matching messages, and you could build a proper matching engine from it.